# how to plot marker on image pixel X Y coordinates on google map

Tags: google-maps

I want to plot marker on the google map image pixels using coordinates. Is there any solution. I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean and provide more info, e.g. visual examples, the code you've tried so far, etc.?

Comment: i mean that how to find the exact point in the image in the Javascript where i can plot marker

Comment: Sorry, what image? Any image? Or are you referring to a map loaded via the JavaScript API? To place a marker on a given location you need lat/lng coordinates which you can get using the Geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: Or using the Places API, see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047640/add-marker-in-google-maps-with-flutter