# Add marker in google maps with Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

I have managed to create a google map in my flutter app and I am able to show my location and also markers using latitude and longitude. Does anyone know how to create a marker for a business which already exist in google map? What should I pass to the marker to identify a business which is already in google map??? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) or [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) service to find an existing business, and then pass the lat/lng coordinates you get from the results, in `geometry.location`, to a marker's position so that the marker is placed on that business' location, as demonstrated in those linked examples.

Hope this helps!